# How to plot a continuous color wheel with specific colors in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I'm trying to plot a gradient color wheel with 12 specific colors in specific locations. The aim is to reproduce a clockface environment with colors instead of numbers for a cognitive science experiment. The desired output should be looking like this:

[image: Desired output]

I was able to create the discrete color wheel as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(
  number=c(1:12),
  count=rep(10, 12),
  cs=c('#FE2712', '#FC600A', '#FB9902', '#FCCC1A', '#FEFE33', '#B2D732', 
       '#66B032', '#347C98', '#0247FE', '#4424D6', '#8601AF', '#C21460'))

data$fraction = data$count / sum(data$count)

# Compute cumulative percentages (top of each rectangle)
data$ymax = cumsum(data$fraction)

# Compute bottom of each rectangle
data$ymin = c(0, head(data$ymax, n=-1))

# 15 degrees in radians
deg15 <- 0.26179999

(basicwheel <-
  ggplot(data, aes(ymax=ymax, ymin=ymin, xmax=1, xmin=0, fill= as.factor(number), color='black')) +
  geom_rect(inherit.aes = T) +
  coord_polar(theta="y", start=deg15) +
  xlim(c(0, 1))+
  scale_color_manual(values = 'black')+
  scale_fill_manual(values= cs)+
  theme_void()+
  theme(legend.position = '')
)
```

[image: Here is the discrete color wheel]

I then attempted to adapt this plot by maintaining the pure color value at the centre of each slice, while adding a divergent gradient fading towards the pure color of the previous slice on one side, and towards the color of the next slice on the other side.

I created a matrix with the color values associated with the own, the next, and the previous slices' colors.

```
colmat <- data.frame(number = numeric(length(unique(data$number))),
                     ymax = numeric(length(unique(data$number))),
                     ymin = numeric(length(unique(data$number))),
                     previous_color = numeric(length(unique(data$number))),
                     next_color = numeric(length(unique(data$number))),
                     own_color = numeric(length(unique(data$number))))

for (i in 1:length(unique(data$number))) {
  d <- data %>% subset(as.numeric(number) == i)
  iminusone <- as.numeric(i) - 1
  iplusone <- as.numeric(i) + 1
  previousnr <- ifelse(iminusone > 0, data[which(as.numeric(data$number) == iminusone),]$number, 12)
  nxtnr <- ifelse(iplusone < 13, data[which(as.numeric(data$number) == iplusone),]$number, 1)
  colmat[i, 'number'] <- i
  
  previous_color <- colmat[i, 'previous_color'] <- data[which(as.numeric(data$number)  == previousnr),]$cs
  next_color <- colmat[i, 'next_color'] <- data[which(as.numeric(data$number) == nxtnr),]$cs
  owncolor <- colmat[i, 'own_color'] <- data[which(as.numeric(data$number) == i),]$cs
  ymax <- colmat[i, 'ymax'] <- data[which(as.numeric(data$number) == i),]$ymax
  ymin <- colmat[i, 'ymin'] <- data[which(as.numeric(data$number) == i),]$ymin
  
}

head(colmat)
```

However, I must still be missing something, because the following plot does not display the desired gradients within the slices.

```
(gwheel <-
    ggplot(colmat, aes(ymax=ymax, ymin=ymin, xmax=1, xmin=0, fill=number)) +
    geom_rect() +
    coord_polar(theta="y", start=deg15) +
    xlim(c(0, 1))+
    scale_fill_gradient2(high = colmat$previous_color, mid = colmat$own_color, low = colmat$next_color)+
    theme_void()+
    theme(legend.position = '')
)
```

[image: The result of this latter attempt.]

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this gives you a reasonable replica of the desired image:

```r
library(ggplot2)

cs <- c('#FE2712', '#FC600A', '#FB9902', '#FCCC1A', '#FEFE33', 
        '#B2D732', '#66B032', '#347C98', '#0247FE', '#4424D6', 
        '#8601AF', '#C21460', '#FE2712')

vals <- seq(0, 100, 0.1)

ggplot(mapping = aes(x = 1, fill = vals, group = vals)) +
  geom_bar(aes(color = after_scale(fill)), linewidth = 0.2) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = cs, guide = 'none') +
  coord_polar(theta = 'y', start = pi/2) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]